# Eevee shadow catcher in 2.83 release?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadowcatcher

Is there a shadow catcher in Blender 2.83 release? or still have to use the hack with node editor?

Thanks

Comment: have you looked at the [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes) for yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, no Eevee shadow catcher in 2.83